# Avoiding SQL Injection while dynamically passing table name to query C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I am using string concatenation to pass the table name to command string dynamically but I now this will lead to SQL Injection/

I tried to pass it as Parameter but it won't work, so I searched but I did not get the answer.

Is there anyway to dynamically change table name without needing to use concatenation which will lead me to SQL Injection case?

```
    public DataSet Get_Data()
    {
        string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DConn"].ConnectionString;
        string vTableName = null;

        if (DTP_DateFrom.Value == DTP_DateTo.Value)
        {
            vTableName = string.Concat(DTP_DateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "_HISTORY_DATA");
        }
        else if (DTP_DateFrom.Value != DTP_DateTo.Value)
        {
            vTableName = string.Concat(DTP_DateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyyMM"), "_HISTORY_DATA");
        }

        MessageBox.Show(vTableName);
        string Querystr = @"SELECT [ID]
                                ,[type_1]
                                ,[type_2]
                                ,[type_3]
                                ,[AMOUNT]
                                ,[CR_DATETIME]
                            FROM [DBO].[" + vTableName + @"]
                           WHERE CONVERT(DATE,CR_DATETIME) BETWEEN @P_DATE_FROM AND @P_DATE_TO
                             AND UPPER(ID) LIKE UPPER(@P_ID)";

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            conn.Open();
            
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Querystr, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 15; 
                    cmd.CommandText = Querystr;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_ID", "%" + TB_ID.Text + "%");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_DATE_FROM", DTP_DateFrom.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_DATE_TO", DTP_DateTo.Value);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_TABLE_NAME", "'" + vTableName + "'");

                    ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    
                    da.Fill(ds, "DGV_HISTORY_DATA");

                    DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.Columns["ID"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["DGV_HISTORY_DATA"].Columns["ID"].ColumnName;
                    DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.Columns["type1"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["DGV_HISTORY_DATA"].Columns["type_1"].ColumnName;
                    DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.Columns["type2"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["DGV_HISTORY_DATA"].Columns["type_2"].ColumnName;
                    DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.Columns["type3"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["DGV_HISTORY_DATA"].Columns["type_3"].ColumnName;
                    DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.Columns["dgvAMOUNT"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["DGV_HISTORY_DATA"].Columns["AMOUNT"].ColumnName;
                    DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.Columns["dgvCR_DATETIME"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["DGV_HISTORY_DATA"].Columns["CR_DATETIME"].ColumnName;

                    DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.DataSource = ds.Tables["DGV_HISTORY_DATA"].DefaultView;
                    L_Count.Text = String.Format(DGV_DGV_HISTORY_DATA.RowCount.ToString("###,###"));

                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n GetDGV_HISTORY_DATA \n", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: you surely have a finite list of tables with these columns that you want to be passing in? check `vTableName` is in that list.

Comment: If you *are* planning to inject the value `vTableName` from the C# side of things, then also ensuring you escape any right brackets (`]`) will be important too. Just wrapping the value in brackets (`[]`) doesn't stop injection, as a malicious individual can just could those.

Comment: You only need to make sure that the input is either yyyyMMdd or yyyyMM, and if not reject the input.  Use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to verify the input, and then you have prevented the injection vector.

Comment: What types are DTP_DateFrom and DTP_DateTo?  Are they `DateTime`, in which case you don't have an attack vector.   it's not like you can type in "; DROP DATABASE XXX" into a date picker

Comment: I'd use QUOTENAME combined with check for OBJECT_ID(@name) IS NOT NULL parametrized query to make sure the passed table actually exist. Perhaps also PARSENAME to make sure it doesn't pass a database name etc

Comment: Side note: `WHERE CONVERT(DATE,CR_DATETIME) BETWEEN @P_DATE_FROM AND @P_DATE_TO AND UPPER(ID) LIKE UPPER(@P_ID)` is completely non-sargeable (cannot use indexes). Best to do `WHERE CR_DATETIME BETWEEN @P_DATE_FROM AND @P_DATE_TO AND ID LIKE @P_ID` and then truncate the dates, and change the column collation for `ID` to be case-insensitive

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for your comments , first I had removed `UPPER` function  and that is really helpful second about removing convert date I can not because it is stored  in datetime format and I want all date in specific date like `01/02/2023`

Comment: So you just need to send the parameters in already truncated. For example `WHERE CR_DATETIME >= @P_DATE_FROM AND CR_DATETIME < @P_DATE_TO` with `@P_DATE_FROM='20230201'` and `@P_DATE_TO='20230202'`

Comment: @Charlieface parameters passed in date format but column in database in datetime

Comment: Doesn't matter: when you use the above syntax you will get the full data for the date `2023020` while still using indexes. Think about what it's actually doing: it's getting all data between the beginning of one day and the beginning of the next.

Answer (score 2):

The way to protect yourself against SQL injection when using dynamic SQL is **very simplme**: Use parameters where ever you can, and white-list anything that can't be parameterized.

Since identifiers can't be parameterized in SQL, you have to white-list them before you're using them. In this case, make sure that `vTableName` actually contains the name of a table that has the columns in the query.

That being said, the fact that you have a dynamic query like that raises questions about the database design - having multiple tables with the same columns list is usually a strong indication of a bad database design.

Comment: thanks for your answer but for the last point you said `bad database design.`  it one table that contains more than `13 million records` there is around `500,000` record inserted each hour and when I make query it takes around `4 minutes  or more`.. so I am creating a table for each day and empty original table... I  tried to use  indexes but they are not useful at all... please any suggestion for this case ?

Comment: There are probably better options like partitioning and filtered indexes but to offer a solution that fits your needs and will be scalable you need to consult a DBA that will have access to your actual database and can verify the actual needs. It's way beyond what you can get from a Stackoverflow answer from some random stranger on the internet such as myself. We're talking about professional help here, that will cost you some money.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the input before use, and you can prevent the attack vector:

```
    if (DTP_DateFrom.Value == DTP_DateTo.Value)
    {
        if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(DTP_DateFrom.Value, "yyyyMMdd", out var _))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        vTableName = string.Concat(DTP_DateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "_HISTORY_DATA");
    }
    else if (DTP_DateFrom.Value != DTP_DateTo.Value)
    {
        if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(DTP_DateFrom.Value, "yyyyMM", out var _))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        vTableName = string.Concat(DTP_DateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyyMM"), "_HISTORY_DATA");
    }
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if `DTP_DateFrom.Value` is a string. The c# code in the question indicates that it's a `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`).

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yeah, me too.  I posted this before I realised.

Comment: @Neil No overload for method 'TryParseExact' takes 3 arguments

Comment: I'm going to delete this answer, you already have a DateTime, so there is no need to convert it into a string, just to parse it again.  As I commented on the OP, you do not have a SQL injection attack vector.